# Summarizing distinct values (target yield over several years) from multiple columns in pivot table in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I want to help our orchard manager better predict fruit yields and set targets for yields. I have tried accomplishing this in pivot tables and have been unable to achieve the desired result.

*I think part of my problem is that I do not know how to accurately describe the task I am trying to achieve when searching for solutions*

I would appreciate comments on how I could better word my question, and also any solutions to help me achieve the desired results.

**Background**

We have fruit trees of various species that have been planted each year and that we will continue to plant for the next few years; the first planting was in 2020. There are target yields we would like to achieve based on the Species `CMSP`, planting date `PDATE`, Pruning and training style `PTT`, and rootstock (not shown).
For example, with commercial apple varieties, planted at high density, with a `Tall Spindle` training system, a target yield might look like…

- Year 2: 300 bushels per acre
- Year 3: 600 bushels per acre
- Year 4: 1,000 bushels per acre
- Year 5+: 1,400 bushels per acre

**Objective**

I would like to easily and quickly summarize our harvest yield goals, in bushels, for various levels. For example, I might want to see the target yield for all Fuji apples in 2024, or the target yield of the whole orchard in 2023, or compare the target yield of Block 4 vs Block 5, etc.

As a bonus. It would be nice to have a field that converts bushels to pounds (48 pounds per bushel). And also the ability to predict revenue based on a price per pound or price per bushel that we could change to estimate various scenarios.

**Structure and levels of the Data**

For simplicity, I have only included values for `CMSP` (Species) = Apples and `BLK` (Orchard Block) = “4”. In the attached data. However, there will also be other species such as cherry and pears that have their own yield estimates.

Here is an example of the first 10 rows of my data

| CMSP | VAR | PDATE | PTT | BLK# | ROW | LOC | RpSp | PlSp | TPA | APT | Year2 | Year2y | Year3 | Year3y | Year4 | Year4y | Year5 | Year5y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | Granny Smith | 2021 | Tall Spindle | 4 | B | 1 | 12 ft | 36 in | 1,210 TPA | 0.0008 Ac | 2022 | 0.248 bu | 2023 | 0.496 bu | 2024 | 0.826 bu | 2025 | 1.157 bu |
| Apple | Golden Delicious | 2021 | Tall Spindle | 4 | B | 2 | 12 ft | 36 in | 1,210 TPA | 0.0008 Ac | 2022 | 0.248 bu | 2023 | 0.496 bu | 2024 | 0.826 bu | 2025 | 1.157 bu |
| Apple | Golden Delicious | 2021 | Tall Spindle | 4 | B | 3 | 12 ft | 36 in | 1,210 TPA | 0.0008 Ac | 2022 | 0.248 bu | 2023 | 0.496 bu | 2024 | 0.826 bu | 2025 | 1.157 bu |
| Apple | Golden Delicious | 2021 | Tall Spindle | 4 | B | 4 | 12 ft | 36 in | 1,210 TPA | 0.0008 Ac | 2022 | 0.248 bu | 2023 | 0.496 bu | 2024 | 0.826 bu | 2025 | 1.157 bu |
| Apple | Golden Delicious | 2021 | Tall Spindle | 4 | B | 5 | 12 ft | 36 in | 1,210 TPA | 0.0008 Ac | 2022 | 0.248 bu | 2023 | 0.496 bu | 2024 | 0.826 bu | 2025 | 1.157 bu |
| Apple | Golden Delicious | 2021 | Tall Spindle | 4 | B | 6 | 12 ft | 36 in | 1,210 TPA | 0.0008 Ac | 2022 | 0.248 bu | 2023 | 0.496 bu | 2024 | 0.826 bu | 2025 | 1.157 bu |
| Apple | Golden Delicious | 2021 | Bi-Axis | 4 | B | 7 | 12 ft | 36 in | 1,210 TPA | 0.0008 Ac | 2022 | 0.248 bu | 2023 | 0.496 bu | 2024 | 0.826 bu | 2025 | 1.157 bu |
| Apple | Golden Delicious | 2021 | Bi-Axis | 4 | B | 8 | 12 ft | 36 in | 1,210 TPA | 0.0008 Ac | 2022 | 0.248 bu | 2023 | 0.496 bu | 2024 | 0.826 bu | 2025 | 1.157 bu |
| Apple | Golden Delicious | 2021 | Bi-Axis | 4 | B | 9 | 12 ft | 36 in | 1,210 TPA | 0.0008 Ac | 2022 | 0.248 bu | 2023 | 0.496 bu | 2024 | 0.826 bu | 2025 | 1.157 bu |
| Apple | Golden Delicious | 2021 | Bi-Axis | 4 | B | 10 | 12 ft | 36 in | 1,210 TPA | 0.0008 Ac | 2022 | 0.248 bu | 2023 | 0.496 bu | 2024 | 0.826 bu | 2025 | 1.157 bu |

Here are the structure and levels of the data I printed from `R` (but I am using `Excel` for the majority of my work with this data).

```
    CMSP – The species common name
    [1] "Apple"
    
    VAR – The Variety within the species
    [1] "Cosmic Crisp"        "Fuji (Morning Mist)" "Gala (Imperial)"    
    [4] "Golden Delicious"    "Granny Smith"        "Jonagold (Nicobel)" 
    [7] "McIntosh (MacSpur)"  "pollinator"         
    
    PDATE – The year of planting
    [1] "2020" "2021" "2022"
    
    PTT – The pruning and training system
    [1] ""             "Bi-Axis"      "Tall Spindle" "V-TS"        
    
    BLK – The orchard block where the plant is located (only “4” is listed, but there are 11 total)
    [1] "4"
    
    ROW – The row withing the block (A – P for most blocks)
     [1] "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "H" "I" "J" "K" "L" "M" "N" "O"
    
    LOC – The plant location within the row
      [1] "1"   "2"   "3"   "4"   "5"   "6"   "7"   "8"   "9"   "10"  "11"  "12" 
     [13] "13"  "14"  "15"  "16"  "17"  "18"  "19"  "20"  "21"  "22"  "23"  "24" 
     [25] "25"  "26"  "27"  "28"  "29"  "30"  "31"  "32"  "33"  "34"  "35"  "36" 
     [37] "37"  "38"  "39"  "40"  "41"  "42"  "43"  "44"  "45"  "46"  "47"  "48" 
     [49] "49"  "50"  "51"  "52"  "53"  "54"  "55"  "56"  "57"  "58"  "59"  "60" 
     [61] "61"  "62"  "63"  "64"  "65"  "66"  "67"  "68"  "69"  "70"  "71"  "72" 
     [73] "73"  "74"  "75"  "76"  "77"  "78"  "79"  "80"  "81"  "82"  "83"  "84" 
     [85] "85"  "86"  "87"  "88"  "89"  "90"  "91"  "92"  "93"  "94"  "95"  "96" 
     [97] "97"  "98"  "99"  "100" "101" "102" "103" "104" "105" "106" "107" "108"
    [109] "109" "110" "111" "112" "113" "114" "115" "116" "117"
    
    RpSp – Spacing between rows
    [1] "12 ft"
    
    PlSp – Spacing between plants
    [1] "18 in" "36 in"
    
    TPA – Trees per acre, calculated with this formula….
        43,560 / [(Spacing between rows) X (spacing between trees)]
    [1] "1,210 TPA" "2,420 TPA"
    
    APT = Acres per tree
    [1] "0.0004 Ac" "0.0008 Ac"
    
    Year2 = PDATE + 1
    [1] "0"    "2021" "2022" "2023"
    
    Year2y = APT * 300
    [1] "0.000 bu" "0.124 bu" "0.248 bu"
    
    Year3 = PDATE + 2
    [1] "0"    "2022" "2023" "2024"
    
    Year3y = APT * 600
    [1] "0.000 bu" "0.248 bu" "0.496 bu"
    
    Year4 = PDATE + 3
    
    [1] "0"    "2023" "2024" "2025"
    
    Year4y = APT * 1,000
    [1] "0.000 bu" "0.413 bu" "0.826 bu"
    
    Year5 = PDATE + 4
    
    [1] "0"    "2024" "2025" "2026"
    
    Year5y = APT * 1,400
    [1] "0.000 bu" "0.579 bu" "1.157 bu"
```

**Desired Result:**
Show predicted yield in any give year by multiple different levels of variable.

Notes:

1. If restructuring my data would make the desired result easier to achieve, I am open to doing so.
2. I understand that different varieties of apples, and also species of fruit, will fetch different prices. I'm not sure of the best way to enter estimated prices for different varieties and species.

**Example Desired Pivot Table Result**

|  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Species** | Apple | <--Filter |  |  |
| **Block** | 4 | <--Filter |  |  |
| **Row** | (All) | <--Filter |  |  |
| **Year** | 2024 | <--Filter |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| **$/Pound** | **Variety** | **Bushels** | **Pounds** | **Revenue** |
| $2.41 | Cosmic Crisp | 22 bu | 1,056 lb | $2,544.96 |
| $1.35 | Fuji (Morning Mist) | 21 bu | 1,008 lb | $1,360.80 |
| $1.35 | Gala (Imperial) | 18 bu | 864 lb | $1,166.40 |
| $1.20 | Golden Delicious | 18 bu | 864 lb | $1,036.80 |
| $1.20 | Granny Smith | 2 bu | 96 lb | $115.20 |
| $1.30 | Jonagold (Nicobel) | 18 bu | 864 lb | $1,123.20 |
| $1.30 | McIntosh (MacSpur) | 18 bu | 864 lb | $1,123.20 |
| $0.12 | pollinator |  | 0 lb | $0.00 |
|  | **Grand Total** | **117 bu** | **5,616 lb** | **$8,470.56** |

Comment: I think getting your desired outcome with pivot tables would require a major restructuring of data to a more normalized form.  An alternative resturcture where instead of having two column pairs for year and yield is to have one column where header is the year (e.g. `2024Y`) and the yield as data values. Your desired outcome (the portion below all your filters) could then be built using formulas or powerquery (based on the filter/input section).

Comment: @gns100 To make sure I'm following you, Power Query may likely a better solution to my problem than Pivot Tables? I will go ahead and restructure the data based on your recommendations and see how far I get. Thank you, I appreciate your input.

Comment: I think the main point is which path are you most comfortable using to take the input/filter section and applying it to your raw data to get your output section. I believe pivot tables require additional manipulation that make it unusable for your case. Hence either:  formulas (examples: `let`, `filter`, `vstack`), power query (need to use M language), or even VBA/office scripts.

Comment: once you get past your question, I think you can incorporate slicers for the input section which should enhnace the user experience.

Comment: @gns100 Thanks again for your input. I will need to do some additional reading / learning on the various paths you have suggested for solving my question.